# Editing non-nullable fields of ArcSDE layers in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, editing

I'm using ArcSDE layer in my map project in ArcMap 10. Some of the fields of this layer allow null and some don't. I can't edit the non-nullable ones, neither programmatically (`IField.Editable` is `false`) nor via **Attributes** panel.

Is this the restriction of SDE layers or is it possible to tweak some settings/make some changes in DB schema to allow editing of fields that can't contain null values?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the sdetable commands.
[SDE Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/admincmdref.htm)
My thoughts are...
Your table is versioned?
What dbms are you using?
This [esri forum](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=93&f=1170&t=259356) Thread might point in the right direction.

Comment: No, my table is not versioned. Can this cause problems? Tables are stored in SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I'm not sure. I saw one edn doc that seemed to suggest you need a subtype. But the above forum thread suggested you can call an edit session in versioned and non-versioned gdb differently. however that was for 9.3 I would bet it has changed for 10. I would submit a support request to esri if you have that capability.

Comment: I tried to set up versioning, but it gives me an error: "database user name and current user schema do not match". So I decided to skip it for now

Comment: you are turning on versioning in arccatalog?

Comment: @Bard Nesom: yes, I try to do it in catalog

Comment: administrator (sde) level permissions would be required to enable versioning. There is no real setup, just enable it on a right click, and ok the dialog with or without move edits option  http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/a_short_hi9898730.htm

Comment: I checked today, "sde" user (the one I'm connecting with) is the owner of sde schema. Thanks for the link, I'll look at it

Comment: Note that previous link is for 9.3 there is online help for 10 also if need be. This link from 8/2010 talks about the error you have.  http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/9415-export-shapefile-to-gdb-database-user-name-and-current-user-schema-do-not-match

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing your problems, but ArcMap is perfectly happy to let you edit nullable fields in an ArcSDE database (at least on the SQL Server backend my shop uses!)

Unfortunately, I have no suggestions on solving the problem for you...

Answer (score 0):

Its not something silly like fieldnames that are reserved words? I have seen something similar in the past if i recall correctly... Does it happen to all tables or just a specific one?

Comment: It happens to all tables. Fields that don't allow null are marked as grey in Edit Attributes panel. Shouldn't be reserved words. `GlobalID` is not one of them, is it?

Comment: Not that I know off. Configuring geodatabases is not my strongest point really but I would try using arccatalog and check the settings of the feature class that corresponds to this table